# how to increas gravity for xy direction using corona?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

In my game i have right and left side  buttons.if man reach left side button get gravity in minus values.right side plus value.How to set collision detection for both x and -x  direction.

```
local function onLocalPreCollision( self, event )

        if (left.name == "left")  then
                    physics.setGravity(-10,0)

        end
                    if (right.name == "right")  then
                    physics.setGravity(10,0)

        end
    end

boy.preCollision = onLocalPreCollision
boy:addEventListener( "preCollision", boy )
```

Comment: Puzzled. Gravity/ Anti-gravity?? would be a modifier on movement. Naff all to do with detecting a collision, even if you predicting it.

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson: He wants to change gravity when the player collides with a wall.

Comment: Well I did say I didn't get it, and frankly after your clarification I still don't. Boost off one wall, retard on the other I can see, but that's not gravity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try is code**
you must use self or event

- self is collision object that is boy
- event.target is object that is left or right

  ```
  local left=display.newRect()
  left.name=="left"
  local right=display.newRect()
  right.name="right"
  physics.addBody("static",left)
  physics.addBody("static",right)
  local function onLocalPreCollision( self, event )

  if (event.other.name == "left")  then
              physics.setGravity(-10,0)

  end
              if (event.other.name == "right")  then
              physics.setGravity(10,0)

  end
  end

  boy.preCollision = onLocalPreCollision
  boy:addEventListener( "preCollision", boy )
  ```

Comment: FYI, a more idiomatic way to write `local function onLocalPreCollision(self,event) .. end boy.preCollision = onLocalPreCollision` is `function boy:preCollision(event ) .. end`.